# Why is DOM Explorer Greyed Out in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

Whenever I'm trying to debug a javascript app for the windows store, the DOM Explorer is completely greyed out (e.g. the "Select element" option is greyed out and pressing control-b within my app does nothing when I'm in debug mode).

I've tried the following to no avail:

- A brand new project with nothing in it
- Running VS as admin
- Resetting all of my settings to default web developer settings in VS

Any ideas?

Also, I'm running Windows 8 x64. VS2012 w/ SP1 updates.

Answer (score 1):

Go to DEBUG/ Properties.../, in the `Debugger Type` choose `Script Only`.

Comment: There is no "Debug > Properties" in VS 2015...Where is it here?

Answer (score 0):

In addition, it should be noted that not having the debugger set to `script only` will not disable the `refresh windows app` but will prevent it from doing anything...